# How to export DDL for non-default schema in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I need to export DDLs for multiple schemas using Oracle SQL Developer. I can export the DDL for the default schema by going to File -> Data Modeler -> Export -> DDL. However, I haven't yet found a way to export the DDL for other, non-default schemas. Is there a way to export these other DDLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the physical model, make sure the schemas are defined, and that you have the modeler preference to export DDL including schema - and it will spit out whatever you have defined.

Comment: I can view non-default schemas by right-clicking on the default connection and selecting Schema Browser, but I'm not sure how to access the physical model for either the default or non-default schemas.